# Refresh style in datagrid bound to datatable WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid, datatable, refresh, styles

I have a `DataGrid` bound to a `DataTable` and the `DataGrid` has a cellstyle that changes the `Foreground` of the numbers in the cells depending on its value (positive-black or negative-red).
When the `DataTable` gets updated, the `DataGrid` is properly updated, so the binding is working fine.
The problem is that the `Style` is just applied when the `DataGrid` is loaded the first time. When the `DataGrid` gets updated by the binding, if a negative number becomes a positive one, the `Foreground` remains red instead of becoming black.

Am I missing something, any propery or event?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's easier for us to help you with an answer if you provide some sample code reproducing the problem

Comment: Yes...Some code would be certainly helpful

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how are you trying to do this.Any way i have tried and it is working fine.Check this code and find out what is going wrong

Xaml:

```
 <StackPanel Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded" >
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <WpfApplication50:ValueToForegroundColorConverter x:Key="valueToForegroundColorConverter"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Valuetemplate">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Value}" Foreground="{Binding Path=Value,Converter={StaticResource valueToForegroundColorConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <dtgrd:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source}"  
                     Name="datagrid"                          
                     ColumnHeaderHeight="25" 
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False"   
                          >
        <dtgrd:DataGrid.Columns>
            <dtgrd:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource Valuetemplate}" Header="Value"/>
        </dtgrd:DataGrid.Columns>
    </dtgrd:DataGrid>
    <Button Height="30" Click="Button_Click"/>
</StackPanel>
```

and in your codebehind

```
 public partial class Window10 : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{  
    private DataTable source;
    public DataTable Source
    {
        get { return source; }
        set { source = value; OnPropertyChanged("Source"); }
    }
    public Window10()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged!=null)
        PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }

    #endregion

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Source.Rows.Add("-1");
    }

    private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Source = new DataTable();
        Source.Columns.Add("Value");
        Source.Rows.Add("1");
    }
}
```

also this converter

```
 class ValueToForegroundColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        int val = 0;
        int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val);
        if (val < 0)
            brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        return brush;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```